# How can I find out the % of Australians that use Ubuntu?

Tags: statistical

I'm researching how quickly Australians adopt open source technology, where can I find statistics that show global adoption rates for Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, based on what data? You don't have to submit any data about your location to start using Ubuntu. And I'm glad I don't have to. This is free, open source software. If you need numbers, you'll have to do some research yourself or search for market research reports. This isn't easy. It's not tracking individual installations for the APT repository connections, `popcon` only logs the number of installations are installing a certain package, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Statcounter may display the general Linux usage percentage in your country. Ubuntu as the most popular distro should have a big part of that percentage.

[Australia OS Stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#os-AU-monthly-201207-201307)

Comment: These numbers are based on browser (user agent) data, so this reflects desktop users. It does not account for *servers* having Ubuntu installed.

Comment: Through is a good start... and we know that most of the servers are running Linux (what percentage is Ubuntu... is a wonder.\)

Comment: @gertvdijk, some time ago Canonical tried to get a sort of handle on things by modifying the UA string of Firefox to include the term "Ubuntu". I don't know what the position is now because, although I use Firefox, I don't use the one from the repos.

Comment: @gertvdijk, here is an oldish link on putting "Ubuntu" in the UA: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showpost.php?p=2002870&postcount=11 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/95847/what-is-the-rationale-for-where-exactly-ubuntu-is-placed-in-the-browser-user-a